# Dictionary elements corresponding to index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that looks something like this:

```py
x = ['6115587', '2062443', '7022702', '6835792', '3837115']
```

And I want to convert this list into a dictionary in this format: `{index:value}`.

```py
x = {0:'6115587', 1:'2062443', 2:'7022702', 3:'6835792', 4:'3837115'}
```

The reason why I want this is for the user to be able to select the valuue simply by entering the corresponding index.

Comment: The user can already select a value from a corresponding index `x[input]`

Comment: I know that but I want to be able to present it in a dictionary...

Comment: There is not much point in converting a list to a index-based dict... You get the same functionality with more memory over-head

Comment: Yes but I want to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a dict using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
>>> dict(enumerate(x))
{0: '6115587', 1: '2062443', 2: '7022702', 3: '6835792', 4: '3837115'}
```

If on the other hand, you need the opposite, i.e., get the index from the element you can do:

```
>>> dict((el,k) for k,el in enumerate(x))
{'6115587': 0, '2062443': 1, '7022702': 2, '6835792': 3, '3837115': 4}
```

Comment: So how do I access, say, `'6115587'`?

Comment: `my_dict[0]` or `my_dict.get(0)` depending on desired behavior

Comment: @OnurOzbek `dict_name[0]`.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I tried both and the output is `None`.  I always select the 0 index to make sure that I am indeed selecting an existing value but it doesn't work.